# What is the url I will give to the ajax when I send json objcet to c# web server

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json

i wrote a java script to send json object to web service in c#. My web service has a method to retrieve json object called getPerson(String text){}. I can`t understand what is the url that I will give to ajax.This is my java script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function BindJson() {

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();

var $pString = {"firstName": "Rukshi"};

       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: $pString,
                datatype: "json",
                url: "http://localhost:54884/Service1.asmx/getPerson",

                success: function (data, status) {
        alert("ok");
                },
                error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.status);
                }
     });

}
```

Comment: is `url: "http://localhost:54884/Service1.asmx/getPerson",` not it?

Comment: But code is not working.I thought because of the url.Is there anything wrong??

Comment: You can go to service1.asmx  in your browser and see if it is correct